# How do I create a Rewind Functionality for YouTube video

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

Hi Friends I want to develop a rewind functionality that when i clicked on rewind button the YouTube Video which is shown in I-frame rewind for 10 sec But I could not get How can I Create this If you have any solution Please share with me soon.

> Here is my code.

```
    [![<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Youtube videos proxy server</title>
<!--        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php        
        $val="";
        $vid="0TvTyj5FAaQ";
        $str = file_get_contents('video.json');
        $json = json_decode($str, true);
        foreach ($json as  $value) {
           if($value\["id"\]==$vid){
               $val="TRUE";
               break;
           }else{
               continue;
           }
           }           
             if($val=="TRUE"){ ?>
        <div>
            <div style="height: 345px;width: 700px;background: black;">
                <span style="color: white;">This video has restricted content.</span>
            </div>
        </div>  
             <?php }else{
        ?>
        <div id="player">
        <iframe id="player" width="700" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $vid?>?enablejsapi=1&showinfo=0&rel=0"> </iframe>
        <br/>
        <button id='rwnd' onclick="rewind()" >Rewind</button>
        </div>
             <?php } ?> 
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var player=document.getElementById("player");
          var rewind= function(){
              if (! player){alert("no obj");
              }else{

            alert('hello');
            var currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
            console.log(currentTime);
            if(currentTime>5){
            player.seekTo(currentTime - 5, true);
            player.playVideo();
        }
    }
    };
    </script>

    </body>
</html>][1]][1]
```

> Here is video.json file.

```
[
{
"id": "0dV1Bwe2v6c"    
},
{
"id":"0dmhKtQ74wo"
},
{
"id":"0dV1Bwe2v6c"    
}
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Friends I got the answer now hope it will help you too. json file is same as in the question i added in code.

> Here is the solution....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Youtube videos proxy server</title>
<!--        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php        
        $val="";
        $vid="0TvTyj5FAaQ";
        $str = file_get_contents('video.json');
        $json = json_decode($str, true);
        foreach ($json as  $value) {
           if($value["id"]==$vid){
               $val="TRUE";
               break;
           }else{
               continue;
           }
           }           
             if($val=="TRUE"){ ?>
        <div>
            <div style="height: 345px;width: 700px;background: black;">
                <span style="color: white;">This video has restricted content.</span>
            </div>
        </div>  
             <?php }else{
        ?>
        <div id="player1">
        <iframe id="player" width="700" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $vid?>?enablejsapi=1&showinfo=0&rel=0"> </iframe>
        <br/>
        <button id='rwnd' disabled>Rewind</button>
        </div>
             <?php } ?> 
   <script type="text/javascript">
        var player;
        function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
              events: {
                'onStateChange': onPlayerReady
              }
            });
        }
        function onPlayerReady(event){
           if(player.getPlayerState()===1 || player.getPlayerState()===2){
                $('#rwnd').prop('disabled', false);
                $( "#rwnd" ).click(function() {
                rewind();
              });
            }else{
                $('#rwnd').prop('disabled', true);
            }
    }
    function rewind(){
            var currentTime = player.getCurrentTime();
            if(currentTime>10){
            player.seekTo(currentTime - 10, true);
            player.playVideo();
        }else{
            player.stopVideo();
           console.log("Try to rewind video when current playing time greater than 10.");

        }

    };
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```