# Rewind YouTube video with JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website with a embedded video from youtube that stats with certain time.

```
document.getElementById('video').innerHTML='<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+video+'?autoplay=1&start='+timecode+'"</iframe>'
```

I need to show periodiclly only certain clip of video, let say, from 23 to 33 sec. How I can implement it?
Can I rewind video back to 23 after 10 seconds?

Comment: You need to use the YouTube API. Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122278/how-do-i-create-a-rewind-functionality-for-youtube-video

Answer (score 1):

#### You can't - at least not using the DOM.

This is because the YouTube video is hosted within an `<iframe>` with a restrictive cross-site/cross-origin setting that prevents scripts in the parent page (i.e. scripts that you control) from interacting with content loaded into the `<iframe>` - this is to prevent people from being tricked into loading a web-page with a full-page `<iframe>` that loads a YouTube video as the current user (assuming they're simultaneously logged-in to YouTube) and having scripts in the parent page nabbing data/information or impersonating the user by making account changes via the iframe.

#### But you can by using the YouTube scripting library...

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

This library uses the safer technique of `postMessage` to safely send and receive messages to the nested iframe instead of directly interacting with its DOM.